# A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

I am getting "A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" error .Can any one help with this? I have tried Decimal.TryParse but couldn't solved it.

```
gvUploadedFiles.DataSource = new GeneralBL().GetUploadedFiles(
    ObjectTypeCode, decimal.Parse(hdnObjectID.Value),null);
```

Comment: You're passing a string that doesn't parse to a decimal. Stop doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `decimal.TryParse`, like this:

```
decimal theValue;
if (!decimal.TryParse(hdnObjectID.Value, out theValue)
{
    // display error message. The value is not a valid decimal
    // then exit with error
}
```

Use the parsed value here.

```
gvUploadedFiles.DataSource = new GeneralDL().GetUPloadedFiles(
    ObjectTypeCode, theValue, null);
```